# Android Studio can't resolve Espresso 3.0.0

Tags: android, dependencies, android-espresso

According to the [Android Espresso documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/setup.html) to date:

> **Add Espresso dependencies**
>
> To add Espresso dependencies to your project, complete the following steps:
>
> 1. Open your app’s build.gradle file. This is usually not the top-level build.gradle file but app/build.gradle.
> 2. Add the following lines inside dependencies:

```
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.0'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.0'
```

I created a new project and the generated app/gradle file was like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.app.test"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

When I change it to the following:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.app.test"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    // App's dependencies, including test
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:22.2.0'

    // Testing-only dependencies
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.0'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.0'
}
```

I get the following errors:

> Error:(29, 24) Failed to resolve: com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.0
>
>     Install Repository and sync project
> Error:(30, 24) Failed to resolve: com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.0
>
>     Install Repository and sync project

I have tried clicking on the "Install repository and sync project" link but nothing happens. I have also tried looking through the SDK manager, but I can't really see anything.

Comment: Do you import dependencies from [Google's maven](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/testing-support-library/packages.html#gradle-dependencies)?

Comment: Oh my gosh! Again fragmented documentation hurting me! Everything I tried on the project gradle didn't work, except that. Thank you

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As the solution from comment is solving the problem I am adding it as an answer for others:

Be sure to add [Google's maven](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/testing-support-library/packages.html#gradle-dependencies) link to main `build.gradle` file:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As a note I did have to upgrade my support annotations to "compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.4.0'" in the app/gradle file as well

Answer (score 1):

Simply,
Adding `google()` into `allprojects > repositories` will do the trick here...

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can downgrade the version, somehow sometimes the targeted version is unavailable from the repo.
use IDE-UI to select the latest version:

1. Right click on your project folder, select `Open Module Settings`
2. search for the package you want in the dependencies, for example
   [image]

This way, you'll never get an un available version
(of course remember to set proper repo in `build.gradle`, too)

Answer (score 0):

use these versions

```
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.5'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
```